# how to get previous item in array with some filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Currently this is how I go back to previous page/ item:

```
var count = 1;
prev = fetchPrevPage[($.inArray(current, fetchPrevPage) - count + fetchPrevPage.length) % fetchPrevPage.length];
```

the fetchPrevPage contains array of pages visited:

```
["getConversations", "getContacts", "getConversations", "getMessages", "reply", "messageInterval", "messageInterval"]
```

Now what I want to do is, after getting the value of `prev`, I should filter like below:

```
anotherArray = ["reply","messageInterval"];
```

> 1) the value of `prev` must not be same with `current`. `current` is a
>   variable where I store current page name.
>
> 2) If it is same, it should keep going back to previous page.
>
> 3) after the above filter, it should now check against `anotherArray`
>   which contains certain pages. If the value of `prev` match any one in
>   the new array, it should go back to previous page until it meets these
>   conditions.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I found it much simpler to not add the current page if it's the same as the last, when I implemented something similar.  That way you can always go to the last page in the array when you want to go back.

Comment: @Naga, I tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mbKfT/